# linux log rotate for PostgreSQL not rotate the log when log reached threshold

Tags: linux, postgresql, bash, logrotate, log-rotation

I am trying to the setup and control PostgreSQL logs by Linux log rotate as the following

`logrotate_PostgreSQL.conf` file looks like this

```
/var/log/PG/*.log {
    size 10K
    rotate 10
    copytruncate
    missingok
    delaycompress
    nomail
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
       /bin/kill -HUP `  systemctl show --property MainPID  postgresql-15.service | grep MainPID | sed s'/=/ /g' | awk '{print $NF}' ` 2>/dev/null  || true
    endscript
}
```

as we can see from above we defined the size to 10KB , so once `postgres.log` log reached the 10KB then  log rotate should create the backup log as `postgres.log.1`

we activate the log rotate as the following

```
 su postgres -c '/usr/sbin/logrotate  -d /etc/logrotate_PostgreSQL.conf
```

and output is like this

```
reading config file /etc/logrotate_PostgreSQL.conf
Allocating hash table for state file, size 15360 B

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/PG/*.log  10240 bytes (10 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/PG/postgres.log
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/PG/postgres.log, log->rotateCount is 10
dateext suffix '-20230827'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/log/PG/postgres.log.10 to /var/log/PG/postgres.log.11 (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 10),
renaming /var/log/PG/postgres.log.9 to /var/log/PG/postgres.log.10 (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 9),
renaming /var/log/PG/postgres.log.8 to /var/log/PG/postgres.log.9 (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 8),
renaming /var/log/PG/postgres.log.7 to /var/log/PG/postgres.log.8 (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 7),
renaming /var/log/PG/postgres.log.6 to /var/log/PG/postgres.log.7 (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 6),
renaming /var/log/PG/postgres.log.5 to /var/log/PG/postgres.log.6 (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 5),
renaming /var/log/PG/postgres.log.4 to /var/log/PG/postgres.log.5 (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 4),
renaming /var/log/PG/postgres.log.3 to /var/log/PG/postgres.log.4 (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 3),
renaming /var/log/PG/postgres.log.2 to /var/log/PG/postgres.log.3 (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 2),
renaming /var/log/PG/postgres.log.1 to /var/log/PG/postgres.log.2 (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 1),
renaming /var/log/PG/postgres.log.0 to /var/log/PG/postgres.log.1 (rotatecount 10, logstart 1, i 0),
copying /var/log/PG/postgres.log to /var/log/PG/postgres.log.1
truncating /var/log/PG/postgres.log
running postrotate script
running script with arg /var/log/PG/*.log : "
       /bin/kill -HUP `  systemctl show --property MainPID  postgresql-15.service | grep MainPID | sed s'/=/ /g' | awk '{print $NF}' ` 2>/dev/null  || true
"
removing old log /var/log/PG/postgres.log.11
error: error opening /var/log/PG/postgres.log.11: No such file or directory
```

but when  we are looking under `/var/log/PG`

we see the following

```
du -sh *
123M    postgres.log
552M    postgres.log.1
84K     postgres.log.2

 ls -ltr
total 690416
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres     85064 Aug 27 21:00 postgres.log.2
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 578772465 Aug 27 21:05 postgres.log.1
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  68130128 Aug 27 22:08 postgres.log
```

so we can saw that `postgres.log` not rotated even we defined the size to **10KB**

what is wrong with my configuration?

references -

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-cause-postgres-log-pglog-always-rotate-1-gb
https://www.mohitkhare.com/blog/manage-logs-with-logrotate/

Comment: Logrotate typically runs via cron on a daily schedule. It will only check if its over size every 24hrs.

Comment: what is the diff ? I can run logrotate also from cli , in order to rotate the logs  and for test , in any case I run it from cron under /etc/cron.d every 10 min